# What are these balls of wool bound together with a rubber band?

Tags: fiber-crafts, material-identification

I am trying to look up what these are, to no avail:

[image: Fuzz balls]

*Note: this was the closest thing I could find*

They are balls of wool, cut into small pieces, with a rubber band stuck in the middle holding it together.

The closest thing I could describe them as is "fuzz ball", but that's too general. I'm trying to create one. I need to search a tutorial for it but that is difficult when I am not sure what this is.

Comment: Is it a solid sphere? Or do they have a hole through the middle like a fuzzy doughnut?

Comment: @Erica It is divided into two sides because of the rubber band, and there is a slight hole.

Comment: When you say _this was the closest thing I could find_ does that mean what is pictured is not exactly what you are looking for? Mostly because that does not look like wool?

Comment: Do you honestly have any reason to believe that this is related to arts and crafts? They look like a finished product to me.

Comment: @Catija Does not appear to be directly related if you look at my answer. I think a meta about this concept might be in order.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be related to arts and crafts and the image is only an approximation, not the actual item. Please consider editing the question to explain why this is A&C related and include a photo of the actual item you're talking about.

Comment: You have changed the question slightly now by changing the image. If the old image is not what you wanted they why use it? This current image is also just taken from the internet as well. At this point I would like to know what you plan on using this knowledge for because I don't know where to go with this now.

Comment: They just look like pom poms attached to an elastic now. They appear to be a fashion accessory.

Comment: @Matt That is a better approximation until I can take a picture of the one I found. And I'm trying to create one, but I need to search a tutorial for it.

Comment: Are you not then just looking for the answers here: http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/454/how-to-make-a-pom-pom/463#463

Comment: Related meta discussion: http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/212/what-guidelines-should-we-set-for-identification-style-questions

Comment: If your sister has made them before... why don't you ask her what they are?

Answer (score 3):

These are just pom poms on elastic  bands. Those particular ones appear to be made from rabbit fur. That is, according to the less that useful description given from the [site where this image came from](https://detail.1688.com/offer/42835438463.html?spm=a261b.2187593.1998088710.155.4hFbIe).

> Korea cute fashion real rabbit fur ball hair ring hair rope single ball wholesale

<sup>Page appears to be in Chinese Simplified and that is what I got from Google Translate</sup>

The ones pictured are used as decoration or as an accessory.

Coincidentally we had another user ask about how to make those recently. Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/454/how-to-make-a-pom-pom) and you should get an idea of what to do. The only thing that is different is the presence of the elastic band. If you do want that it would just be a matter of attaching that into the pom pom as it is being created.

Comment: My first thought was scrunchie too, but couldn't figure out how that might relate to crafts! :)

Comment: @Erica The thing is you could add all kinds of materials to crafts where that is no their reason for being. Intent would be useful in that case. In _this_ case the answer is the same.

Comment: I don't believe this is it. I'll take a picture of one I found.

Comment: @Peanut I have updated my answer based on information that was changed in the question as well as comments. If something is still wrong please try to avoid changing the question too much as it will invalidate answers. You can also come into chat or ask in meta if you are not sure. Hopefully this will help you.