# How can I finish the tops of my balls so the stitches are not so open in appearance?

Tags: crocheting

Pokemon Go has been a feature in my family, and the world, as of late. I figured it would be fun to make some pokeballs for the kids. The first time I make something I expect there to be flaws. I make mistakes so that I can learn from them. However I have now made two balls which have similar issues that I see when I make spherical objects.

[image: Tops of my balls]

As you can see the tops of the balls have rather open stitching. I don't have this issue with the bottoms, which is where I started working, as they are tight and closed.

[image: Bottoms of my balls]

[Based on the instructions I was following](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pokeball-Set/), which are pretty much the same for all balls, I just did the reverse of the inc rows using dec's for the top. When I made the first ball the rows stopped leaving a large circular gap at the top. I added some more stitches to round it off.

How can I finish the tops of balls and other spheres so that it looks tighter and not obvious that I finished there.

Comment: Possible similar question (not a duplicate): http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/454/how-to-make-a-pom-pom

Comment: Consider additionally crocheting them top down, so the prettier beginning part is the one you see more often.

Comment: I actually do that know for that reason. Hiding among he white is much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an amazing tutorial for [how to close amigurumi shapes](http://www.buddyrumi.com/blog/2013/7/12/light-bulb-closing-3d-amigurumi-pieces.html). It's a bit of work but the results are beautiful.

Essentially, this method works by creating an identical system to your opening [magic loop](http://www.crochet-world.com/blog/?p=7618) (if you're using the magic loop start), by adding a drawstring to the last circle of stitches. This drawstring can then be pulled until the circle is completely closed and then tied in place and finished off.

[image: Closing Amigurumi spheres]

As laid out in the tutorial, the steps are:

> 1. Decrease the opening in your work until you have 6 to 8 stitches or less.
> 2. Thread a tapestry needle with the tail left from your work. Insert the needle under the next front loop.
> 3. Repeat for the remaining stitches pulling the yarn lightly.
> 4. Pull the yarn tightly until the hole closes completely.
> 5. Insert the needle under a loop close to the closed hole. Repeat one more time.
> 6. Pull the yarn until creating a loop and insert the needle into the loop. Pull the yarn creating a knot.
> 7. Insert the needle into the closed hole and make it come out as far as possible.
> 8. Pull the yarn until the knot disappears into the piece. Cut the yarn close to the piece, the end will disappear inside it.
> 9. Piece closed.