# How do I make pom poms not fall apart as easily?

Tags: preservation, yarn

As we learned in [How to make a pom-pom?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/454/how-to-make-a-pom-pom) they are fairly easy to make. The problem is that they are just as easy to take apart.

So you could get your pom pom trimmed to make the perfect sphere and it takes little to no effort to pull individual strings from the ball. Do this enough and the integrity of the ball starts to fail and exacerbates the issue and they can start to fall out on there own.

I noticed that *all* of the commercial products that use pom poms e.g. clothing, toys, etc. do nothing to prevent this (Wife hates it when I test them). That tells me it is not a huge issue that industry, as a whole, does not attempt to mitigate it. It's not that can't. I'm sure its a matter of cost justification and its not worth it.

However, when I make something I would like it to last as long as possible.

What can I do to reduce the likelihood of a pom pom falling apart? Or at least slow it down. Glue comes to mind.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next to the methods in the answer by user18849, stronger string, tighter knot and wet string to tie, you can stitch the center of the pompom.

Prepare the pompom as usual, but instead of just putting a circle of string around it, you punch a needle through the bunch of yarn in the middle of the pompom, combined with going around. 
For this you want strong sewing yarn, in a colour that is near of that of the pompom. (But if you have no other, black or white should not show in a well filled pompom.)

You need to go through and around, through and around, etc, quite a few times. In theory you need to go through each of the yarns twice, in practice you will go through one many times and missing an other completely. This is why you will still need to tie very tightly.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make the pom-pom not fall apart as easily you have to pull the string tighter when making a knot. Some tips to consider:

- loop the string about 3 times before making the final knot
- use your finger to hold the string in place when making the knot
- try using a different (not yarn) string for the knot – a thin and strong one (so that it doesn’t break when pulled tight)
- if you are using the same yarn to tie the knot as the one the pom-pom is made of, and you are using natural yarn, then try soaking the knotting string (just that string) in warm/hot water and make the knot while it is still wet (it should shrink when it dries, giving you a tighter knot)

I guess the reason why pom-pom manufacturers don’t do anything about it being  easy to pull separate strings from a pom-pom is because pom-poms are not meant to have their strings pulled out one by one, and they turn out to be just fine if you don’t do that.

If you feel like you need to use glue anyway, try it, and share your results.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried several methods found online.

1. Stitching through the pompom works.
2. Use waxed thread/string and a triple knot to tie tightly.
3. Tie the wool to attach to a hat or gold ribbon for Xmas pompoms round as well and the waxed thread doesn't show.
4. Then tie round the pompom at right angles to the first one also with the waxed thread and triple knot in this direction too. This holds the pompom together pretty well.
5. I have done this cross over to existing pompoms to stabilize them.
6. Waxed floss works as well and is really invisible.
   Hope this helps. Eileen